# Why did this synthesis of Aspirin fail?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I tried to synthesize acetylsalicylic acid(aspirin) by the method below. However, I definitely failed and got something unknown.

The method used was:

1. Add 2.5 g of salicylic acid(about 2494 mg), 3.0 ml of acetic anhydride, and 5 drops of concentrated(85%) phosphoric acid to a 50-mL Erlenmeyer flask.
2. Heat the flask with a hot water bath at about 70°C for 5 minutes. The solution should be transparent after the reaction.
3. Add 2 mL of distilled water to the flask. After a minute, take off the flask from the water bath and add 20 ml of distilled water to the flask. Then put the flask in an ice bath and get crystals.
4. Collect the aspirin crystals by vacuum filtration. Use a Buchner funnel and dry filter papers. Scrape out the solid in the flask with a glass rod and dump on the filter paper. Rinse it with 5 mL of distilled water.
5. Dry the aspirin in 110°C oven for 5 minutes. I get about 2556 mg of aspirin.
6. Take 1 g of aspirin and follow a process similar to 1-5. Add 15 mL of diethyl ether and 1 g of aspirin to a 50-mL Erlenmeyer flask. Then heat the reaction with a hot water bath at about 50°C. Take off the flask and add 15 mL of petroleum ether to the flask. Put the flask in an ice bath and get white needle shaped crystals. Collect the crystals by vacuum filtration. Rinse it with petroleum ether. Finally dry the crystals in 110°C oven. (Recrystallization)

When I took them out after 5 minutes, they was slightly less dry. (now I get about 311 mg) I wanted to use a melting point apparatus, so I continued heating a little more. However, it melted...

[image]

It seems that new substances have been formed instead of aspirin. Especially, at the point where there were filter holes, black powder like something created. I wonder what these could be.

When I was synthesizing aspirin (at method 3), crystals formed unexpectedly because the temperature of the hot water bath slowly decreased. However, since the solution was already transparent enough, I believed it would not have a significant impact. Additionally, the aspirin was not finely powered but rather in chunk form. But I also believed it would not be a major issue.

Comment: Some SWAG: 1. There was dirt in the apparatus. 2. Chemicals were impure (phosphoric acid, for example, may attack a paper lid-seal, carbonizing it). 3. At some point the reactants overheated. For example, in step 1 of the exercise, heat may be evolved. It might be necessary to add them slowly, with cooling, until mixed.

Comment: What is the meaning of the first sentence in § 6 ? I copy it here in italics : *Take 1 g of aspirin and follow a process similar to 1 - 5 ?* Do we have to add acetic anhydride and phosphoric acid to this aspirin like in paragraph 1?